# How to compute limit of $(1/a+2/a^2+...+n/a^n)$ when $n\to\infty$

Tags: limits

I'm doing some calculus, and I found this specific problem

***`lim(1/a+2/a^2+...+n/a^n) when n->inf`***, and I have not a single idea how to compute it.

Comment: Cf. [Arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence)

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{2}{a^2}+...+\frac{n}{a^n}\right)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{a^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{a^k}
\end{align}
Let $1/a=x,$ so we have
\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k}{a^k}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^k\\ 
&=x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}
\end{align}
Now, let
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kx^{k-1}$$
So
$$\int f(x)dx=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int kx^{k-1}dx$$
The RHS equals
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{x}{1-x}\text{  for $|x|$<1, i.e., $|a|>1$}$$
So
$$f(x)=1/(x-1)^2$$
i.e.,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{2}{a^2}+...+\frac{n}{a^n}\right)=\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{a}{(a-1)^2}\text{  for $|a|>1$}$$
$\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}=\frac{a}{(a-1)^2}$ can be easily found using simplification, so don't be confused.

Answer (score 1):

This is [arithmetico–geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence).

The answer is $\dfrac a{(a-1)^2}$ when $a>1$.

See that link for a proof.

Comment: The series is evaluated in $a^{-1}$, therefore the condition should be $\lvert a\rvert>1$.

Comment: Thank you, @Gae.S.; I edited accordingly